# Multiplying strings in a list by numbers in another list (Python)

Tags: python, list

What I have:

```
names = ["Bob", "Dora", "Kelly"]
numbers = [5, 3, 2]
```

What I need:

```
list1 = ["Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Dora", "Dora", "Dora", "Kelly", "Kelly"]
```

Such that their names are appended to a new list times i number of times as indicated by my numbers list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and a list comprehension:

```
[name for name, count in zip(names, numbers) for _ in range(count)]
```

`zip()` pairs up each name with each number, the list comprehension uses a nested set of `for` loops to repeat `name` the right number of times.

Demo:

```
>>> names = ["Bob", "Dora", "Kelly"]
>>> numbers = [5, 3, 2]
>>> [name for name, count in zip(names, numbers) for _ in range(count)]
['Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Dora', 'Dora', 'Dora', 'Kelly', 'Kelly']
```